# Connect to PostgreSQL Data Source in Grafana via SSH Bastion

Tags: postgresql, ssh, grafana

I am using Grafana Cloud for a PoC project, and the long and short of it is that I cannot find a way to securely connect Grafana and the PostgreSQL data source.

For obvious reasons we do not allow any direct connections to our database and instead use jump hosts with individual SSH keys for access.

I have looked for a `Connect to PostgreSQL via SSH` option and found nothing, I am curious if anyone else has faced this, as it seems like it would be a common issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to setup an ssh tunnel on the machine/instance that is hosting Grafana, tunnel through the jump host directly to postgresql. There are some pretty good docker-compose setups to do that.